# Checking difference in days only with LAG in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need a bit of help but I'm very close to achieving what I'm looking for thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523906/find-users-who-worked-for-5-consecutive-days-with-date-range-in-output). However, it's not exactly the output that I need.

Using LAG to check for differences in dates, I need LAG to ignore differences in time and consider only dates. In other words, it should consider only calendar days, not 24-hour days. Is there any way to achieve that?

Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
SUM(DIFFERENCE) AS DAYS,
DATE_IN,
DATE_OUT
FROM (
    SELECT *
        FROM (
          SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT, ACTIVE,
          NVL(DATE_IN - LAG(DATE_IN) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID, ACTIVE ORDER BY DATE_IN), 1) AS DIFFERENCE
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE MY_TABLE.ACTIVE = 1
    AND TO_CHAR(DATE_IN, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= 'user-selected date'
    AND TO_CHAR(DATE_OUT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= 'other user-selected date'
    )
)
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT
ORDER BY DATE_IN
```

The ouput I get:

```
    EMPLOYEE_ID | DIFFERENCE           |  DATE_IN          |        DATE_OUT
    000199         1                     2013/11/25 08:41:00    2013/11/25 16:41:00
    000199         0.970833333333333     2013/11/26 07:59:00    2013/11/26 15:59:00
    000199         1                     2013/11/27 07:59:00    2013/11/27 15:59:00
    000199         1.00069444444444      2013/11/28 08:00:00    2013/11/28 16:00:00
    000199         1                     2013/11/29 08:00:00    2013/11/29 16:00:00
```

What I'm looking for:

Differences here should all be 1, time should be ignored. I've tried TO_CHAR(DATE_IN .......) in LAG to get rid of the time part but of course that didn't work :p

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of Googlers:

```
 TRUNC(DATE_IN) - LAG(TRUNC(DATE_IN)
```

Is the key to ignoring time and getting a result only for days.

Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for the answer and for teaching me about TRUNC in the process :)